# Any recommendations for Magento<>SAP B1 Integration tools/ connectors

Tags: orders, tierprice, integrate, group-price, offers

We are looking into solutions for Any recommendations for Magento (Community Edition - Ver 1.5.1.0)<>SAP B1 (Version 9) Integration tools/ connectors.

Can anyone suggest/ recommend a solution they have implemented successfully to achieve a really successful/ slick intergration between these two platforms.

We would look to achieve individual customer discounts/ group product discounts based on a 'standard' price list in SAP. We want a solution that is very fast, with little server resource, and without massive data sync if possible.

We want to be able to 'sync'-

- Web orders. (inc Backorders if poss)
- Customers (all details to create accounts on Magento and registrations back into SAP as CRM leads)
- Prices (from multiple price lists)
- Individual customer pricing/ discounts/ product group discounts/ special product discounts/ special offers etc
- Stock levels (live)
- Product details/ descriptions/ images - creating products in SAP for Magento
- Administration / management of items/ customers on SAP to enable, disable etc.

If you can give me some possible solutions, and your experiences of these if you use them, that do all or most of the above that will be greatly appreciated.

Cheers in advance.

Comment: You can try appseconnect.com

Comment: Thanks Rahul thats one name I have already in the mix thank you for this. Do you possibly have any other suggestions as an alternative to APPSeConnect please???